# (DynamoDB) ConditionExpression behaves unpredictably with an '=' operator. How could I debug it better?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

My objects in Dynamodb look roughly like this:

```
{ 
  userId: "GEFOeE8EsaWmq4NQ3oh7tbeVkLx1",
  url: 'objectURL', 
  object: {}
}
```

I have this simple piece of code for deleting an object, when the user that owns the object requests a delete. The user argument here is a parsed JWT, by the way.

```
export async function deleteObject(user, url) {
    let params = {
        TableName: OBJECTS_TABLE,
        Key: {
            url: url,
        },
        ConditionExpression: `userId = :uid`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":uid": {
                S: user.sub
            }
        }
    };
    let deleteResult = await dynamoDb.delete(params).promise();
    return deleteResult;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, and I've made sure that the problem stems from the ConditionExpression by changing `=` to `<>`. I simply get this:
 `ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed`

I'm sure solving the problem wouldn't be difficult, but I barely have any information

Questions:

1. Why is the condition expression failing? Everything looks alright, and it should work. Right?
2. How could I debug this issue better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. ExpressionAttributeValues can be directed used, without mentioning the datatype. The Javascript SDK does that automatically.

```
export async function deleteObject(user, url) {
    let params = {
        TableName: OBJECTS_TABLE,
        Key: {
            url: url,
        },
        ConditionExpression: `userId = :uid`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":uid": user.sub
        }
    };
    let deleteResult = await dynamoDb.delete(params).promise();
    return deleteResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `await/async` is not supported by AWS SDK at the moment. Please refer this similar [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/12).

> The SDK currently relies on CLS to trace the call context. It doesn't
>   work with async/await functionality right now. You can see the
>   discussion [here](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage/issues/98).

It should work if you remove the `await`. Example below:-

```
let deleteResult = dynamodb.deleteItem(params).promise();
deleteResult.then(function (data) {
    console.error("Delete item result :", JSON.stringify(data,
        null, 2));
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error("Delete item result error :", JSON.stringify(err,
        null, 2));
});
```